# Sql server query with data group and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem in a query. Actually, I am getting output as follow:

```
ID    Key     KeyCount
----------------------
1     Key1    1
1     Key1    1
2     Key2    2
2     Key2    2
```

I want the output as:

```
ID    Key     KeyCount
----------------------

1     Key1    2
2     Key2    4
```

Thanks.

Comment: why Key2 count is 4 ?

Comment: Key count is sum of keycount am i right ? if yes then there are 3 instad of 4 for key2.

Comment: Right. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   SELECT ID,Key,sum(keycount) keycount from yourTable group by id,key
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Group by and i am assuming keycount has sum of keycount in resultset.

```
SELECT id, min(key) as key , sum(keycount) as keycount from tablename GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Key, sum(keycount) as keycount from yourTable group by id,key
```

try above SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest question for any beginers , if you realy want to learn SQL kindly first google it or refer some documents or books and then try of your own

simply puting here and geting answers will not help much , this was my perception ,rest all up to you..

Cheers :)